# Search nsarray of nsdictionary

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, search, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an `NSArray` filled with `NSDictionaries`. One of the keys the dicts have in common is "name". I have another array, filled with names. I want to search the first array, if it finds a name it is supposed to add the dictionary to a third mutable array. The third array then contains all dictionary which names are in the name-array.

Comment: To be honest, now that Rahul posted his answer I feel sort of stupid because this is actually simple and I don't know why I didn't think of this. I guess I imagined it to be more difficult...:)

Comment: ["When in doubt, use brute force."](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/k/kenthompso185574.html)

Comment: ["Next to being witty, the best thing is being able to quote another's wit."](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/c/christiann142148.html) ;P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use "fast enumeration", commonly also known as for-in loop:

```
for (NSDictionary* dict in myArray) {
```

Also, to compare NSString's, use -isEqualToString:.

```
   if ([[dict objectForKey: myKey] isEqualToString:myString]) {

   }
```

Comment: You can also send `containsObject:` to the array of names, passing the name from the dictionary, rather than writing the inner loop through the array of names yourself.